# IE JavaScript prompt

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prompt

I need to ask for a password for my donload-site.

I tried to use the following script but it doesn´t work with IE

```
window.onload = function Passwort () {

  var Passwort = "asdf";
  var Eingabe = window.prompt("Bitte geben Sie das Passwort ein", "");
  if (!Passwort);{
  if (Eingabe != Passwort) {
    alert("Falsches Passwort!");
  } else {
      document.getElementById("content").style.display="block";
  }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an Idea what the Problem could be? 
Thank you!

Comment: You have a `;` after the `)` from your `if`. The condition is also "if not Passwort", which will always be `false` in your code (`!"asdf" === false`)

Comment: "*..but it doesn't work with IE..*": Are you saying that it works in all other browsers?

Comment: It works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Comment: @PaulS.: The Op says that the code works in FF, GC and AS ;)

Comment: ***What*** doesn't work? How is it behaving differently from what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var Passwort = "asdf";
  var Eingabe = window.prompt("Bitte geben Sie das Passwort ein", "");
  if (Eingabe != Passwort) {
    alert("Falsches Passwort!");
  } else {
      document.getElementById("content").style.display="block";
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn´t work, IE alerts "Falsches Passwort"

Comment: @user3632480 It works fine for me on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CJ2SU/ What version of IE are you using?

Comment: It has to work with IE8 unfortunately. I solved the Problem with PHP now! Thank you anyway! :)